# Console Error "imageInput.fileupload is not a function" while uploading image via django-summernote

Tags: jquery, django, summernote

I was trying to upload an image to django-summernote text editor. And in the chrome developer tools console I found this. Please help me

```
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "media_cdn")

SUMMERNOTE_CONFIG = {
'iframe':False,
'airMode':False,
'styleWithTags': True,
'toolbar': [
    ['style', ['style']],
    ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
    ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'height']],
    ['insert', ['link', 'picture']],
],
'disable_upload': False,
'internal_css': (
static('django_summernote/summernote.css'),
),
    'internal_js': (
static('django_summernote/jquery.ui.widget.js'),
static('django_summernote/jquery.iframe-transport.js'),
static('django_summernote/jquery.fileupload.js'),
static('django_summernote/summernote.min.js'),
),
'attachment_upload_to': MEDIA_ROOT,
'attachment_model': 'django_summernote.ImageAttachment',
'attachment_storage_class': 'django.core.files.storage.Storage',
```

}

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: check it now...please help!